# Can a process lock a disk so that no other process can access it?

Tags: linux, locking, disk

Is there a way for a process to lock an entire disk so that no other process can access any file on the disk until this process releases the lock? Disk i/o operations for the other processes would presumably block until the lock is released.

The OS in question is Linux.

Comment: Well, I'm guessing you could lock all files and folders of the disk, but that could be pretty slow...

Comment: Lock the disk or lock access to all files on the disk ? Locking files can be achieved by umounting,  and your program can still access the disk by /dev/sd*. (But other IO will just fail)

Comment: How about locking an entire directory on the disk, then?

Answer (score 0):

Since everything on a Linux it's a file, you should try locking the file representing your device.

Comment: This requires first unmounting the disk, which is undesirable, because it will cause I/O operations for other processes to fail (rather than to block, which is what I'm after).